# Creating a Click Event for A Dynamically Created Button On A Dynamically Created Tab

Tags: c#, winforms, button, tabs, click

I am having trouble creating a click event for a dynamically created button on a dynamically created Tab.  I keep having an exception thrown.  The program creates a Tab for each directory within a directory and then creates a "+" button that is supposed to allow the user to add more text boxes to the page.

Here is the tab creation code:

```
    private void addTabs(int tab_Number, string assetName)
    {

        TabPage newTab = new TabPage(assetName);
        prjct_Directory_Setup_Tab.TabPages.Add(newTab);

        // tabs need a unique id to maintain state information
        newTab.Name = "Tab_" + tab_Number;

        // add text to the tabs
        newTab.Text = assetName;

        //Add tab Labels
        Tab_labelPositions(assetName, newTab);

        //Create a new flow panel
        FlowLayoutPanel mainTabFlowPanel = new FlowLayoutPanel();

        //Add the control to the tab page
        mainTabFlowPanel.AutoScroll = true;
        mainTabFlowPanel.AutoSize = true;
        mainTabFlowPanel.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.TopDown;
        mainTabFlowPanel.Location = new Point(13, 134);

        //Add the control to the tab page
        newTab.Controls.Add(mainTabFlowPanel);

        //Add the picture folder labels to the flow panel
        findAllFolders_inAssetFolder(assetName, newTab, mainTabFlowPanel);

        Point buttonLocale = new Point(156, 22);
        String addFolders = "addFolders" + tab_Number;
        //createButton(buttonLocale, "+", addFolders, newTab);

        Button newButton = new Button();

        //create a new size
        Size buttonSize = new System.Drawing.Size(75, 33);

        //setup the button
        newButton.Name = addFolders;
        newButton.Text = "+";
        newButton.Location = buttonLocale;
        newButton.Size = buttonSize;

        newButton.Click += new EventHandler(this.newButton_Clicked);     

    }
```

Many thanks for any help!

Comment: *I am having trouble creating a click event* - what kind of trouble? Exception? It works not as expected? Please clarify what kind of trouble you have and provide only related code

Comment: `BadUserException` ? There are plenty of strange things: calling location as *locale*, comments, etc. Could you tell please what exception and at which row?

Comment: Apologies I am new to the forum so if I didnt clarify everything my bad.  I am getting to following exception: Argument Exception was unhandled, Delegate to an instance method cannot have null 'this'.  It occurs on the button event handler.    There are probably plenty of strange things in my code as I am new to c#.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
....
Button newButton = new Button();    
newButton.OnClick += (s, p) => { your onclick code here };
...
```

Or

```
....
Button newButton = new Button();    
newButton.OnClick += newButtonOnClick; //where newButtonOnClick is a method you define in your class

private void newButtonOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    //insert code here
}


...
```

Comment: +1 for the lambda, but you should still keep proper naming when possible :P

Comment: I wont be able to try this code until tonight but I appreciate the help!  I will try renaming.  Is there a particular reason having buttonLocale vs buttonLocation would be very bad?